# Custom Cell load NIb work on ios 6 but crashed on ios 5

Tags: xcode, uitableview, xcode4.5, loadnibnamed

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    }
```

works perfect with ios 6 simulator but crash on ios 5 simulator with the following error:
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The NIB data is invalid.

did apple changed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some suggestions!

If you created this project with a recent version of Xcode (Xcode 4.5 or 4.6), the CustomCell nib has autolayout turned on by default. But there is no autolayout in iOS 5.

Also your code is wrong in both iOS 5 and iOS 6. If you're getting your cell from a nib, do not use `loadNibNamed:`. Instead, register the nib with the table view, with `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:`. Now when you call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` the nib will be loaded automatically if necessary. Note that there must be only *one* top-level object in this nib, and it must be the cell. It's a dumb rule, but that's how it is.

Comment: thanks for you answer.
im unchecked the autolayout, now the cell is loaded but when im clicking on a row i get this error:
'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named NSLayoutConstraint'

and.. im pretty new to ios development so i didnt really understand what should i have to do with this method registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:
if you can give me a sample code i would be greatful.

Comment: about the error, i fixed it.
if you can explain me about the registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: its would be nice..

Comment: Hi @user1600694, here's sample code: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/ch21p606addCellSubviewsInNib/p515addCellSubviewsInNib/RootViewController.m